# How to inject properties values in service while creating the unit test case for controller

Tags: micronaut

I am working on a micronaut application where I have added a property inject in the service class like this:

```
@Value("${scheduler.jobtime}")
private final String cronExpr;
```

This is how my service class look like:

```
@Context
@AllArgsConstructor
@Slf4j
public class MyService {
    private final ExternalApiClient externalApiClient;
    private final OtherService1 otherService1;
    

    @Value("${scheduler.jobtime}”)
    private final String cronExpr;

    public Job createJob() {
        
       // Method definition using externalApiClient
    }

    public boolean haveStartedToday() {
        return otherService1.somemethod(cronExpr);
    }
}
```

As I have added this property my following test case is getting failed

```
@MicronautTest(transactional = false)
@Tag("integration")
class ControllerTest {
    private static final UUID ID = UUID.randomUUID();
    @Inject
    @Client("/")
    HttpClient client;

    @Inject
    MyService myService;

    @MockBean(MyService.class)
    @Context
    MyService myService() {
        final MyService mock = mock(MyService.class);
        when(mock.createJob()).thenReturn(Job.builder()
                .status(“CREATED”)
                .fullLoad(true)
                .build());
        return mock;
    }

    @Test
    void executeJob() throws JSONException {
        HttpResponse<String> response = client.toBlocking()
            .exchange(HttpRequest.POST(“/job”, ""), String.class);

        verify(myService).createJob();

        assertThat(response.code()).isEqualTo(HttpStatus.OK.getCode());
        Map<String, Object> hashMap = Map.of("id", ID, "status", “CREATED”);
        JSONAssert.assertEquals(response.body(), new JSONObject(hashMap), 
        JSONCompareMode.LENIENT);
    }
}
```

I can see the error is as follows

```
Bean definition [com.endpoints.job.$ControllerTest$MyService0Definition$Intercepted] could not be loaded: Error instantiating bean of type  [com.endpoints.job.$ControllerTest$MyService0Definition$Intercepted]
```

I believe it's because of the properties added in service class but not sure how to resolve this.

Could anyone suggest if i am missing anything.

Thanks

Comment: Remove `@Context` from your MyService mock. If this does not help please provide the code of MyService.java

Comment: @saw303 tried that, not working. updated the service code in the question

Comment: Can you switch to constructor injection?

Comment: @knittl before that I would definitely like to understand issue with the current code

Answer (score 0):

Without a [Reproducer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) cannot replicate your exact issue.

Possible issue is because of Lombok.

```java
@Context
@AllArgsConstructor // Creates MyService(String str) constructor
public class MyService {

    // Without @AllArgsConstructor this won't compile because it is final
    @Value("${my.property}")
    private final String str; 

    public String doSomething() {
        return "doSomething -> property: " + str;
    }
}
```

With Micronaut version 3.8.3 the error I get is:

```
io.micronaut.context.exceptions.BeanInstantiationException: Bean definition [com.example.MyService] could not be loaded: Failed to inject value for parameter [str] of class: com.example.MyService

Message: No bean of type [java.lang.String] exists. Make sure the bean is not disabled by bean requirements (enable trace logging for 'io.micronaut.context.condition' to check) and if the bean is enabled then ensure the class is declared a bean and annotation processing is enabled (for Java and Kotlin the 'micronaut-inject-java' dependency should be configured as an annotation processor).
Path Taken: new MyService(String str) --> new MyService([String str])
```

Because Micronaut doesn't know what "String" you want to use in the constructor.

**UPDATE**

Works if you change `@AllArgConstructor` to `@RequiredArgsConstructor`.

```java
@Context
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class MyService {

    private final Transformer transformer; //Injected by constructor

//    @Value("${my.property}") //Works, but use @Property 
    @Property(name = "my.property") //Preferred over @Value
    protected String str; //Cannot be final! Private requires reflection. 

    public String doSomething() {
        return transformer.transform(str);
    }
}
```

Comment: AllArgsConstruction is already used in my Service and for the String part shouldn't it get picked from application-test.yml/application.yml

Comment: If Lombok retained the annotation and created a constructor like `public MyService(@Value("${my.property}" String str)` then Micronaut would know what string you wanted to set. The `@AllArgsConstructor` worked before because `ExternalApiClient` and `OtherService1 ` are beans.